# jQuery Mobile 1.4.4 - icons not showing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have just started using jQuery Mobile for an ASP.NET site which will have certain pages designed expressly for touch/tablet access. JQM certainly seems the way to go, but for some reason I am unable to get icons to show, even when I keep it very simple and only use CDN hosted JS and CSS, as follows:

```
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js" ></script>
</head>
```

and then in the body:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<a href="#options" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="dialog">Options</a>
```

This all seems standard. The only possible thing I can think of is that I am testing using a Microsoft Surface 2 running Windows 8.1 RT and IE11 - but surely this can't be the problem? Can anyone confirm that this should work?

Jon

Comment: Does the browser support SVG?

Comment: @omar -- good point -- OP - see this update for svg icons on IE11 you might need -- http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2925451 -- alternatively visit -- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/icons/ -- on your tablet and see if the icons are displayed correctly

Comment: I should have thought of that - but, yes the icons do show in the demo page, so not a browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

mmh.. this should work but also, you should avoid data-rel="dialog" (deprecated) but instead data-rel="popup" and set data-dialog="true" in the dialog page.

Comment: OK - I was just using a sample page (http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_icons.asp) on W3schools for initial testing. I can go to that page on my tablet and the icons show. But if I copy the same code from the head and first part of the body of that page into my own page the icons do not show. Weird.

Comment: After a bit more investigation, if I simply open the HTML file on my tablet the icons display in IE11. But if I try to retrieve exactly the same HTML page from my server (running Windows Server 2003, IIS6) over my LAN then the icons do not appear. Must be something simple and obvious but I can't see it.

Comment: Still haven't cracked this. I can retrieve the HTML page from the web server into IE10 on my desktop and the icons show.  I can open the HTML file locally in IE11 on my tablet (as stated above) and the icons show. But if I retrieve the same HTML page from the web server into IE11 on my tablet, the icons are missing and the layout is not correct (header bar not shaded, buttons not rounded etc). So it does not appear to be a matter of browser version or of retrieving the page from a web server, or of paths - so what on earth could the difference be?